# CheckBoxMultipleChoice with CheckGroup

Tags: java, wicket

I implemented CheckBoxMultipleChoice with items at run time, now I need to complete with an option to mark all. 
I have used the CheckGroup but apparently it is not working, any advice is welcome.

Here is my html code:

```
<span wicket:id="group">
<input type="checkbox" wicket:id="groupselector"> check/uncheck all </input>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div wicket:id="contratos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

And java Code:

```
Form<ContratoList> formData;
    add(formData = new Form<>("formulario", new CompoundPropertyModel<>(contratoListIModel)));
    CheckGroup group = new CheckGroup("group");
    group.add(new CheckGroupSelector("groupselector"));
    group.add(new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<>("contratos",
            TipoServicio.getTodos(), TipoServicio.getCR()).
            setOutputMarkupId(true)); /* Here get items, works fine*/
    formData.add(group);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CheckBoxMultipleChoice` you should use a `CheckboxMultipleChoiceSelector`.

Just remove the `CheckGroup`, it is an alternative to CheckBoxMultipleChoice, not something to be used together.